# Handle distinction between Swedish Social Security numbers (SSN) and organisation numbers

Tags: c#

Swedish social security number or national identification number (Swedish: personnummer) is usually formatted like this:

- YYMMDDNNNN
- YYMMDD-NNNN
- YYYYMMDDNNNN
- YYYYMMDD-NNNN

All organisations and companies have organisation numbers (Swedish: organisationsnummer) that are in the following format and looks like Swedish SSN:

- XXXXXXXXXX
- XXXXXX-XXXX

Is there anyway to do a programmatic distinction to see if it is a organisation number or SSN? Preferably in C#.

Comment: What happens if more than 9,999 Swedish babies are born on the same day?

Comment: @juharr I ran into this while researching my question. Actually it can handle less, the last digit is only a control digit and the second last is odd for boys and even for girls. What happens when we reach 500 boys or girls the same day is the real question (at the moment Sweden is around 300). July 2014 had an average of 352 boys a day. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identity_number_(Sweden)#Checksum
http://www.scb.se/sv_/Hitta-statistik/Artiklar/Manga-barn-fods-under-var-och-sommar/

Comment: @Ogglas In Austria, it is the exact same system. And there are indeed cases with more than 500 boys per day. In this case, the birth date on the social security number is **2014-13-32**, i.e. a fictional date which does not exist! **A software should be able to handle this.** BTW: This is mostly due to immigrants from countries with low standards where many people are "officially born" on January 1 or June 1.

Comment: @George Interesting! However Sweden does not create a fictional number. Current solution, translated: "Because the number of SSN is limited, it can happen that birth numbers run out for a given day. A person born on a day like this can instead get a social security number where the Birthday digit is a nearby day instead." Therefore my code below will work, at least in Sweden.
http://www.skatteverket.se/privat/folkbokforing/omfolkbokforing/personnumretsuppbyggnad.4.18e1b10334ebe8bc80001502.html

Comment: @Ogglas Ah that's interesting. In any case it means that you cannot deduct the birth date from the social security number. In Austria I know some programs which do this and now I know that they are wrong.

Comment: @George Correct, funny that we discussed this yesterday and today the largest news media in Sweden have a story about it: "Fabricated birthdays when personal numbers runs out". It's about a guy who cannot travel because his Syrian ID says January 1st but his Swedish says 2nd January. http://www.svt.se/nyheter/lokalt/skane/pahittade-fodelsedagar-nar-personnumren-tar-slut

Comment: @Ogglas yeah, what a funny coincidence! ;)  And I thought so that this might lead to problems. Because it is a very rare case. That guy might perhaps need a document from the authorities where they explain that the social ID is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. :)

Organisation numbers looks like personal identity numbers but have a "month" number of 20 or higher so that a [distinction is possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identity_number_(Sweden)#Similar_identity_numbers). The lowest organisation number therefore becomes like this:

- XX20XXXXXX
- XX20XX-XXXX

Therefore we can check the first number in "month" to see if it is either a 0 or 1 (01 January... 10 October etc).

Code that can handle all of the above, needs some error checking to use in production though:

```
public bool IsSwedishSsn(string identity)
{
    identity = identity.Replace("-", "");

    if (identity.Length == 12)
        identity = identity.Substring(2, 10);

    return bool socialSecurityNumber = identity.Substring(2, 1) == "0" || identity.Substring(2, 1) == "1"; 
}
```

Comment: It's nice that you learned something today, but is this information really that relevant to other programmers? It's rather "too localized" (a close reason that doesn't exist anymore), the more generic question _"How to recognize the Nth character in a string to be a number, and being higher than X or lower than Y"_ (or subsets thereof) have been asked and solved plenty of times before. And why don't you solve this problem at the input side, providing the user with two different inputs, so that they can enter either an SSN or an organization number?

Comment: Wouldn't this only work sometimes? What happens when an organization number is also a valid identification number? Example: 1601011234. Couldn't that be either?

Comment: @CodeCaster I actually gave it some thought if I should post this or not but in the end I thought it was worth it. I was working on a project where we needed to do this and I could not find any similar question on SO. It took some time to find the "month" code and I really think it can help some Swedish programmers in the future, or anyone else having to make the same distinction.

Comment: @hatchet I can't happen since the "month" number is always greater than 20 in a organisation number. Both systems are handled by the state as well so it probably won't change. :)

Comment: You didn't make that distinction in the question, and it's not really clear in the answer either. You say an org number can be XXXXXXXXXX, which implies they could be any 10 digit number.

Comment: @hatchet Thanks for pointing it out, made a clarification in my answer because the question is like I saw it at first.